# Can I ask a question about a custom scripting language?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I recently asked a question and was reminded that pseudocode is not allowed on this site; I translated it because I felt the original code would have been confusing. The reason being that the scripting platform I'm coding for is likely a custom built one (using VB6 probably...something old) for a botting program of a very old game and has syntax like this:

```
dim @var1,@var2,@var3     //declare 3 variables
let @var1,=,1             //set var1 to 1
let @var1,+,1             //increment var1 by 1
if @var1,>=,2,label1      //on success jump to label1
goto label2

label1
print variable1 is >= 2
end                       //ends the script

label2
print variable1 is < 2
end
```

I've never seen this syntax anywhere else but I may just be uninformed. The botting program is called ASSA, for the game StoneAge, and is written by some dude (so the audience is fairly limited, probably only in enthusiast circles). How then, should I ask this question (or can I)?

For reference, the question (now deleted) is this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245277/find-a-positive-number-within-range-without-using-modulo

Comment: What did you translate from and to? If you don't know the name, can you point to the company / product / page that contains this language.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Added more information about the platform. It's a botting program called ASSA for the game StoneAge. As far as I'm aware there is no website.

Comment: Thanks. I'm failing to find a GH or other page about it, do you have a link?

Comment: @Peilonrayz For which one? Assa is long dead as it was released in a now defunct forum, circulated only by enthusiasts now. The game doesn't even have an english wikipedia page (here's the japanese one: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%A8%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B8_(%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0))

Comment: We support a lot of odd languages, but there does have to be a compiler or interpreter available. Doesn't have to be free (we have [tag:matlab] questions), but it has to be available. Is there one available for your language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can I ask a question about a custom scripting language?

Yes, if there is a compiler / transpiler / interpreter that we can obtain to run the language through.

---

> I translated it because I felt the original code would have been confusing.

If we can review [BrainFuck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/brainfuck/info) and [LOLCODE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/lolcode/info) I think we can handle some old looking language. *If we can find out what it is and what we can do in it*.

> I've never seen this syntax anywhere else but I may just be uninformed.

The language seems basic, very basic. It has declarations, the operators are prefixed by a `let` and it uses gotos and labels for control flow.

> Assa is long dead as it was released in a now defunct forum, circulated only by enthusiasts now.

Given that it seems like all information about this language is now lost in history getting a good review in this language is likely to be hard or impossible.

---

> How then, should I ask this question (or can I)?

If you can provide us with a link to the compiler / transpiler / interpreter in the body of your question then you can ask with any language.

However this is much more likely to go unanswered then if you were to translate the code into a different language like Python, JavaScript, C or anything else.
**Note**: if the code is translated, it will be reviewed as-is with no regards to the original code. (Thanks @[Mast](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast))

Comment: Thanks! I will translate it then as the interpreter is lacking one critical function if not connected to an active instance of the game.